# SignalR websocket on Owin self host

Tags: websocket, signalr, owin

I was trying SignalR on Owin Self host. Everything works file but SignalR falls back to server send event instead of using WebSockets.
I know IIS 7.5 (Windows 7) does not support websockets but since this is Owin Self host, I was under impression that it is not dependent on IIS and HTTP.sys and websockets should work.

Even Scott Hanselman commented on below link that with OWIN we can do WebSockets anywhere:
https://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/3090811-websockets-support-in-asp-net-4-5-should-not-be-li

Does anyone how how to do true websockets with SignalR (or any other approach) and Owin running on Windows 7?

Comment: I use WebSockets with old Windows versions (prior Windows 2012/8) using an external framework. Since you are already self-hosting your app, if you are willing to not go through SignalR and/or OWIN it may be also a valid option.

Comment: hi  vtortola, please share more details around the framework. Can I download and try it?

Comment: http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/ This is the one I develop and maintain. There are others like SuperWebSockets or AlchemyWs. I objectively recommend mine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OWIN WebSocket spec doesn't have any OS dependencies, but it does rely on having a server that implements it. Try Nowin: https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin

HttpListener used in Katana self-host still depends on Http.Sys and requires Win8+ for WebSocket support.